# how to take List<Point> from mil.nga.sf.Geometry

Tags: java, geopackage

In my mil.nga.sf.geometry object I am getting `geometry type, hasM, hasZ and point`.

In my debugging I am able to see that geometry object contains list of point objects, But I am not able to take them into a list.

I am able to get the methods like `getGeometryType, hasM(), hasZ()` methods, but when I try to say `geometry.getPoints`  it is not showing that method

In my geometry object I am getting List, but I am not able to take them into a list.

How can I take that `list< point>` into a list.

```
mil.nga.sf.Geometry geometry = GeometryReader.readGeometry(reader);
```

Comment: [Geometry](https://github.com/ngageoint/simple-features-java/blob/master/src/main/java/mil/nga/sf/Geometry.java)  class don't have any Points its a extend class from Geometry , may be rendered object is different type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LineString to get the `List<Point>`

```
LineString geometry1 = null;  
    List<Point> points = null;     
    if (geometry instanceof mil.nga.sf.LineString) {
           geometry1 = new LineString((mil.nga.sf.LineString) geometry);
    }
    if(null != geometry1) {
        points = geometry1.getPoints();
    }
```